A is second only to B as the + [plural or singular]?

Research indicates that vehicle pollutants are the second biggest contributor to climate change, only after industrial plants.

I'm trying to rewrite this sentence using a new idiom I've just learned--second only to. However, I'm not sure if I should use contributor or contributors after as the. I mean there are two contributors mentioned here, but the real focus is on vehicle pollutants.

Research indicates that vehicle pollutants are second only to industrial plants as the biggest contributor(s) to climate change.


The presence of industrial plants is immaterial.  We are concerned only about the ranking second biggest.
The plurality of contributor(s) follows vehicle pollutants' are (where the various pollutive components are considered separately),
and hence we
use the plural contributors.

Research indicates that vehicle pollutants are second only to industrial plants as the biggest contributors to climate change.

Ranking numbers like the biggest or the second biggest
shouldn’t prohibit the use of the plural.
are the biggest contributors

Thank you. I meant to regard all the pollutants as a whole--as the second biggest contributor. I guess the singular is also correct, isn't it?

You can say second biggest contributor, but then you are reverting to your original pattern that you're wanting to avoid. The syntax is "A is/are second only to B as the biggest contributors to X". Is/are depending on whether A is singular or plural. Contributors is plural because you are listing the two biggest items on the list.
